# Jaxlib installation failure

Tags: pip

I'm trying to install jaxlib using pip through my terminal, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib
```

The only people who had the same problem are using Windows, I'm on a Mac tho. I don't know if it is because I'm using Pyenv, but that shouldn't be the problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Currently downloadable files](https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/0.1.74/#files) include wheels for Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. No source code.

Don't be too haste to upgrade to Python 3.10, its ecosystem is not fully ready yet. Downgrade to Python 3.9.